# Filter a related list based on a check box from another related list

Tags: apex, javascript, custom-object, related-list, inputcheckboxes

Is it possible to filter the related list based on a check box from another related list? If so what is the best way to achieve this. The current relationship is all based on custom objects and fields.

I tried creating an apex page, but so far I was not able to achieve this. Is there a better way, such as javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a visualforce page that would:

1) Take all selected selected checkbox value and store it inside of a list

2) Place all the value of the list into a query filtering out your resultlist

3) Retrieve the resultlist and display accordingly

Comment: Hi Dotmiko, I am really new at apex could you please provide a link or an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a visualforce page wherein you can control this custom behaviour

Comment: Hi Anshul, I tried doing this, but I really new at apex. could you please provide a link or give me an example on how I can accomplish this.

Comment: @MicroSumol : I would recommend going through Visualforce developer's guide to better understand how visualforce pages can be developed. For your specific problem, I might not have an example code ready (as it's very specific), would suggest you to work on it and if you face any problems, post them in this forum.